# Understanding how native Mac applications should be organised

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have just started investigating the differences between creating Mac applications and iOS which I have now become quite comfortable with. One of the main issues I'm having is finding resources on how I should be organising my app as any Cocoa developer would do on the Mac. With iOS I am used to utilising `UIViewControllers`/`UITableViewControllers`, and storyboards. The paradigm seems different on the Mac, obviously having windows changes things.

The application I want to begin with will have just one window, with a small pop-up window occasionally and also a preferences screen. The main window will also have a bunch of tabs that users can access different information from. My main question would be how to structure this - using the default Mac template it loads for me the xib file and depends on the AppDelegate to work with the UI. Should I be creating a subclass of `UIWindowController` to then load the nib file and work with my UI from there? If so is there somewhere I can read on how nibs work with the `UIWindowController`s?

Any other tips on what is different in structuring Mac apps code-wise versus iOS would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend [this blog article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html).

Answer (score 1):

NSWindowController is your equivalent of a UIViewController (its like a root NSViewController), there are NSViewControllers also but they are not as important, you also have a NSDocument which is also a controller, Mac apps divide the controller laying into view controllers (NSWindowControl) and model controllers (NSDocument), NSDocument is responsible for controlling the model, serialising it, view controller are more like presenters in the model view present paradigm, where a NSWindowController (and NSViewController) represent the XIB file, fill out field values, act as delegates to view objects etc. In some simple apps you can do away with a NSWindowController and let the NSDocument handle the controller lay completely itself, I though nearly always create a NSWindowControler it not difficult and its constant with the steps I normally take.

Comment: +1 Good overview. While not relevant to the OP's one-window system, it is also important to be aware of `NSDocumentController`, which is commonly a top-level object for multi-document applications.